# Stack trace error when using standard AX auto report

Tags: axapta, x++

I get a stack trace error (DictField object not initialized.

Stack trace

(C)\Classes\SysQuery\packDataSource - line 65
(C)\Classes\SysQuery\packDataSource - line 148
(C)\Classes\SysQuery\packRangeAndSortorder - line 37
(C)\Classes\SysQueryForm\querySave - line 18
(C)\Classes\SysQueryForm\buildSavedQueriesMap - line 21
(C)\Classes\SysQueryForm\buildSavedQueriesBox - line 8
(C)\Forms\SysQueryForm\Methods\run - line 5
(C)\Classes\SysSetupFormRun\run - line 9
(C)\Classes\QueryRun\prompt
(C)\Forms\SysTableForm\Methods\queryOpenDialog - line 10
(C)\Forms\SysTableForm\Designs\DesignList\QueryBtn\Methods\Clicked - line 4

)when I try to select a range for any auto report(Click select from the report dialog)  when generating a standard ax auto report. This only happens when I try to generate the report in the details form.(It works fine on all listpages but fails in the detail page). To generate I go to File -> Print -> Print/Print Preview this shows a dialog then I click select to set the range. On click of select the error is thrown. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: There are probably too many variables to figure this out w/o having a developer look at it. I'd guess there may be a hotfix out for this and/or try resetting your usage data.

Comment: @AlexKwitny: Resetting the usage data took care of the problem. Thanks Alex

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset your usage data.

Comment: @Lawrence: Please take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)